# how to search a control in an asp.net gridview and access it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, findcontrol

I have a gridview as :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAppRejProfiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Resumes
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnResumes" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

i have a list of resume names (string format) that i want to add as the text of the linkbutton "lbtnResumes" for all the resume names that i have in a string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make use of `FindControl()` mehod ....to search control

```
void gvAppRejProfiles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton bl = 
         (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbtnResumes");


    }
}
```

Comment: i did this : LinkButton lbtnFound = (LinkButton)gvAppRejProfiles.FindControl("lbtnResumes"); but not working

Comment: you are wrong you need LinkButton lbtnFound = (LinkButton)gvAppRejProfiles.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("lbtnResumes");

Comment: you need to find control in the row of the grid otherwise you will get nothing......hope you got my point

Comment: row of the grid is returning null, i have just checked the rowbound event, and its working

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int count = 0; count < gvAppRejProfiles.Rows.Count; count++)
                {
                    LinkButton lbtnResumes = (LinkButton)gvAppRejProfiles.Rows[count].FindControl("lbtnResumes");
                    if (lbtnResumes.Text == "resume")
                    {
                        // Store and perform any operation
                    }
                }
```